# commonOpenFileDialog could not be found winform

Tags: winforms

I want use CommonOpenFileDialog in winform. I added windowsapicodepack in preferences, but recieved the error shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: like the error says, are you missing a "using" statement at the top of your file? We can't see.

Comment: i finded problem.It don't run in .Net framework 2.0. But i run program then can't created new layer.
''layers" is a Usercontrol

Answer (score -1):

i finded problem.It don't run in .Net framework 2.0. But i run program then can't created new 'layers'.
''layers" is a Usercontrol
[can't create new Usercontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkJc6.png)

Comment: seems to be a file not found exception. I would guess it's expecting some file to be there, which isn't. Maybe check the full detail of the exception, it's hard to be sure just from a screenshot.